# Android song control

Tags: android

How to stop previous playing song before playing next song and i get the after alter my code,this is my altered code

```
public void pl(int songindex)
{
    if(mp.isPlaying())
    {
        mp.stop();
        if(songindex==0)
        {

            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gayatri);
            mp.start();
        }

        else if(songindex==1)
        {

            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.brahma);
            mp.start();
        }   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you click the "next song" button run this code first

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
{
    mp.stop();
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I haven't see your answer while posting, so +1 for first answer

Comment: @Pragnani always happens ;)

Comment: i use that code unfortunately app closed error public void pl(int songindex)
 {
  if(mp.isPlaying())
  {
   mp.stop();
   if(songindex==0)
   {
     
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gayatri);
          mp.start();
   }
   
   else if(songindex==1)
   {
    
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.brahma);
    mp.start();
   } 
  
  }
   
 }

Comment: @PrabuJM It seems your mp is null so please post your complete code where you have declared your MusicPlayer and also post logcat trace

Answer (score 3):

```
public void pl(int songindex)
{
if(mp!=null)
{
 mp.stop()
 ........
 ........\\your code here
 }
 else if(mp==null)
 {
  ...... 
  ......\\your code here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
{
mp.stop();
}
```